# How to synchronize size of a child window in WPF to match that of a parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, user32

I have a MainWindow in WPF that creates another window (Window1) and using SetParent from user32.dll sets MainWindow as parent of Window1.

this is my code for MainWindow

```
Class MainWindow

Dim Window1 As Window1

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Me.Left = 0
        Me.Top = 0
        Window1 = New Window1(New Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle)
        Window1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Window_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
        If Window1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Window1.Width = Me.ActualWidth
            Window1.Height = Me.ActualHeight
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is my code for MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Cyan"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
</Window>
```

this is my code for Window1

```
Public Class Window1

    Sub New(parentWindowHandle As IntPtr)
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim interop = New Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Me)
        interop.EnsureHandle()
        Me.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual
        Me.Left = 0
        Me.Top = 0
        SetParent(interop.Handle, parentWindowHandle)
    End Sub
    Public Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (hWndChild As IntPtr, hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Class
```

and this is my code for Window1 XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Magenta" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
</Window>
```

When I run example code and resize MainWindow the Window1 is also resized. The Window1 size matches MainWindow size.

This is correct behavior.
But if MainWindow has different position, like:

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Me.Left = 10
        Me.Top = 0
        Window1 = New Window1(New Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle)
        Window1.Show()
    End Sub
```

Resizing MainWindow causes Window1 to also move, to the right side.

This behavior is incorrect.
This behavior occurs when MainWindow and Window1 have AllowsTransparency parameter set False.
How can I size Window1 to match the MainWindow size when it resizes?

edit:
here is a video showing project code in visual studio, just so we're clear about the code, this is under net framework 4.6.2.
https://www.veed.io/view/6ef01c2a-73d6-42e0-80fd-8ae096e96b4f

this is chrome code that adds ability to move mainwindow with invisible titlebar.

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome     
        CaptionHeight="10"  
        ResizeBorderThickness="4">
    </WindowChrome>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

and here is a video of a debugging, as you can see when mainwindow is positioned at 0,0 everything works fine, but as soon as i move mainwindow to position that is not 0,0 it causes the child window to move and resize, but no code was added to move window1. https://www.veed.io/view/85db988b-fe22-4548-b92a-1761dd8a2508

this one shows that changing windows to allowtransparency="false" gives expected behavior, meaning that it might have something with how transparent windows are rendered. https://www.veed.io/view/77351d65-f769-4f84-8849-cd3127fee783

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parent Window in the child Window's constructor:

```
Public Class ChildWindow

    Private WithEvents _parentWindow As Window

    Public Sub New(parentWindow As Window)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Store reference
        _parentWindow = parentWindow

        ' Copy parentWindow's size
        With parentWindow
            Me.Height = .Height
            Me.Width = .Width
        End With

        ' Move Window to top left of the screen
        Me.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual
        Me.Left = 0
        Me.Top = 0

    End Sub

    Private Sub _parentWindow_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles _parentWindow.SizeChanged
        ' Update Window's size to values in NewSize
        With e.NewSize
            Me.Height = .Height
            Me.Width = .Width
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

In this code I store a reference to `parentWindow` and handle its [SizeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged) event to adjust the child window's size when `parentWindow`'s size changes. The position of the child window does not change when `MainWindow`'s position changes. Having AllowsTransparency set to False has no impact on this.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the Owner property, however an owner of a window is not the same as a parent of a window.

Comment: @iTDy0lyMSN but isn't this doing what you want, "synchronize size of a child window to match that of a parent"? I've removed the offending Owner code, this answer just deals with answering the question now.

Comment: I tried your code and the results are the same. I uploaded video to better explain what i'm getting.

Comment: @iTDy0lyMSN none of your video links work, they all say "This video isn’t ready".